Why is all text getting uppercased?
Here is the code:
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
            Button("Goodbye World") {}
        }
            .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    SwiftUIView()
}

Here is the preview:

Why is all of my text getting uppercased?
This is happening only in this Xcode project (same code in another project renders just fine). It happens both on the preview and if running the project.
This is getting me mad for two days.
